# Deserialize json string into visual basic object using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject VISUAL BASIC

Tags: vb.net

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject VISUAL BASIC, and i need to deserialize the json string into a object called 'Elemento'.

My code:

```
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
            Dim json As String = "{""where"":""id==" + oid + """, ""selects"":[""current"", ""name"", ""type"", ""revision"", ""owner"", ""description""]}"
            request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody)

Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request)
Dim code As String = response.StatusCode

Dim elemento As Elemento = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Elemento)(response.Content)

Dim tipo As String = elemento.type
Dim current As String = elemento.current
Dim nombre As String = elemento.name
Return elemento
```

The recibed json:

```
{
    "msg": "OK",
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "LABORATORIO",
            "owner": "aviteri",
            "current": "Active",
            "id": "62676.39210.18680.50051",
            "type": "Workspace",
            "revision": "0000000026"
        }
    ],
    "objectsLabels": {
        "name": "Name",
        "owner": "Owner",
        "current": "Maturity State",
        "id": "emxFramework.Attribute.id",
        "type": "Type",
        "revision": "Revision"
    }
}
```

I need to deserialize the 'data' info of the json into my object Elemento, i tried the last code but i am receiving empty information. Just ignore the objectsLabels data.

This is my 'Elemento' class, it has the same properties and few more:

```
Public Class Elemento

#Region "Variables"

    Public Enum Valores
        Nulo
        ParaInformacion
        Rechazado
        RevisadoConComentarios
        RevisadoSinComentarios
    End Enum

    Public Enum Estado
        Privado
        En_Desarrollo
        Emitido
        Completado
        Emitido_Cliente
        Obsoleto
        Active
        Create
    End Enum

    End Enum
    Private _objectID As String
    Private _name As String
    Private _typeName As String
    Private _description As String
    Private _owner As String
    Private _revision As String
    Private _title As String
    Private _originated As String
    Private _modified As String
    Private _estado As Estado
    Private _current As String


#End Region

#Region "Properties"

    Public Property id() As String
        Get
            Return _objectID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _objectID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property name() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property type() As String
        Get
            Return _typeName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _typeName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property description() As String
        Get
            Return _description
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _description = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property owner() As String
        Get
            Return _owner
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _owner = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property revision() As String
        Get
            Return _revision
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _revision = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property title() As String
        Get
            Return _title
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _title = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property originated() As String
        Get
            Return _originated
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _originated = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property modified() As String
        Get
            Return _modified
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _modified = value
        End Set
    End Property



    Public Property current() As String
        Get
            Return _estado
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _estado = CType([Enum].Parse(GetType(Estado), value), Estado)
        End Set
    End Property

#End Region
```

Comment: Post your `Root` class and *the other* class object. (Note that you're trying to access the inner class directly, while you need to deserialize the `RootObject`)

Comment: As already noted, you're missing the `RootObject`. The class with the `msg`, `data` and  `objectsLabels` properties. `data` is a `List(Of Elemento)`, while `objectsLabels` is a single `Elemento`. Btw, you could use just Auto properties and remove all those backing fields (except, maybe, the last one. But you should use a type converter, if you also want to serialize the classes back a JSON).

Comment: Yes that was!!!! Thank you Jimi!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jimi said in the comments, i was missing the RootObject, a class with the msg data and objectsLabels properties.

I have created a class called ResponseListElements

```vb
Public Class ResponseListElements
#Region "Variables"

    Private _msg As String = String.Empty
    Private _data As List(Of Elemento)

#End Region
#Region "Properties"

    Public Property msg() As String
        Get
            Return _msg
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _msg = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property data() As List(Of Elemento)

        Get
            Return _data
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of Elemento))
            _data = value
        End Set
    End Property
#End Region

End Class
```

And them i changed this line:

```
Dim elemento As Elemento = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Elemento)(response.Content)
```

By this one:

```vb
Dim elemento As ResponseListElements = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of ResponseListElements)(response.Content)
```